Set the font-size in the downloaded plot using {plotly}
I am trying to download a 4k .png-image using the modebar via {plotly}. However, the font size is too small when downloaded, as opposed to the rendered plot in R studio.
Changing the scale does not change anything about the font-size in the downloaded plots. Below is minimal working example, with the expected output, and the actual output.
Minimal Working Example
library(plotly)

# 1) generate simple
# plot
fig <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 3, 1), type = 'bar')

# 2) define configuration
# and add text
config(
  fig,
  toImageButtonOptions = list(
    format= 'png',
    filename= 'custom_image',
    height = 2160,
    width  = 3840,
    scale  = 2)
) %>% layout(
  showlegend = TRUE,
  legend = list(
    orientation = 'h',
    x = 0,
    y = 100,
    yref="container",
    title = list(
      text = "<b>Legend:</b>",
      font = list(
        size = 20
      )
    )
  ),
  title = list(
    text = "Title",
    font = list(
      size = 20
    ),
    x = 1,
    xref = "paper",
    xanchor = "right"
  )
)

Expected Output (As rendered in R Studio)

Actual Output (As downloaded via modebar)

Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0

How can I ensure that the font size is scaled and readable in the plot downloaded via the modebar in {plotly}?

I think this Plotly resource will get you where you're trying to go. (Scroll down to 'Customizing Modebar "Download Plot" Button')
